# Why is NTP listenning broadcast IP

Tags: linux, ntp, ntpd

This is a physical SBC machine and customer created many virtual IP (It a related to relem and vnet concept in tele communication)

Here we have created `eth2` and `eth3` as a signalling interface. `eth2` and `eth3` are treated as a `vlan` and bind relem `eth2:6` and `eth3.1238:0` to these `vlan`.

In our case we discard `eth2` and `eth3` from `ntp.conf` because there are multiple relem bind to `eth2` and `eth3` so `ntp` tries to create a socket for each session, and the problem was all file descriptors where exhausted. That's why we add only `eth0` interface and we don't want `npt` to listen on any interface except `eth0` so I have used the interface ignore wildcard option.

However we can see that after making changes in `ntp.conf` it is trying to listen on the broadcast address and failing to bind with an unexpected error.

```
ntpd[89217]: ./../lib/isc/unix/ifiter_ioctl.c:617: unexpected error:
ntpd[89217]: eth2:6: getting broadcast address: Cannot assign requested address
ntpd[89217]: i/o error on routing socket No buffer space available – disabling
ntpd[5410]: ./../lib/isc/unix/ifiter_ioctl.c:617: unexpected error:
ntpd[5410]: eth3.1238:0: getting broadcast address: Cannot assign requested address
ntpd[5410]: ntpd exiting on signal 15
ntpd[1508]: ntpd exiting on signal 15
```

ntp.conf

```
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 10
Authentication stuff
keys /etc/ntp.keys
path for keys file
trustedkey 1
define trusted keys
requestkey 1
server 172.23.5.8 iburst
server 172.23.5.9 iburst
restrict 172.23.5.8
restrict 172.23.5.9
key (7) for accessing server variables
controlkey 15 # key (6) for accessing server variables
extra lines to fix issue about NTP Daemon
interface listen eth0
interface ignore wildcard
```

ip a sh

```
256: eth3.897@eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
link/ether 00:1e:67:53:e0:b2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 169.254.66.8/18 brd 169.254.127.255 scope global eth3.897:0
inet6 fe80::21e:67ff:fe53:e0b2/64 scope link nodad
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
257: eth3.951@eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
link/ether 00:1e:67:53:e0:b2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 169.254.66.118/18 brd 169.254.127.255 scope global eth3.951:0
inet6 fe80::21e:67ff:fe53:e0b2/64 scope link nodad
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 brd 127.255.255.255 scope host lo
inet6 ::1/128 scope host nodad
```

Can any body tell me how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I've been unable to reproduce your issue but I suspect there are a few things at play;

Somewhere you may have an IP address config issue on one of your interfaces (which is why you get the bind error) I do also wonder if you have more than one config file on your system as your earlier question text showed a valid output from `ntpq -pcrv` which meant it was running when you did that test.

In an earlier [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40150029/2) of your question you showed a valid output from `ntpq -pcrv` which indicated that `ntp` was already running. You may have more than one version installed, or trying to run more than once instance - you should also check for that.

Signal 15 is `SIGTERM` - which means 'something' terminated it, rather then it died/crashed etc.

Below is my config file from a production box. (This is a S1 server with a directly connected reference clock but I've removed the redundant bits of config)

```
#YOU SHOULD ALSO ADD:
interface ignore wildcard
interface listen eth0

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
leapfile "/etc/ntp/leap-seconds.3676752000"

restrict default kod nomodify
restrict -6 default kod nomodify
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict -6 ::1

server server1
server server2
server server3
server server4
server server5

#REQUIRES MCAST SETUP/CONFIG
broadcast 224.0.1.1 key 6
manycastserver 239.255.254.254

includefile /etc/ntp/crypto/pw
keys /etc/ntp/keys
trustedkey 6
```

Replace `serverX` with your own upstream servers - you want a *minimum* of 3, ideally 5 servers for robust ntp operation.

Restart ntp and wait a while - then run `ntpq -pcrv` and check the output. Below is mine for reference;

```
    ntpq -pcrv
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
-server1         10.10.10.14      2 u   50   64  377   29.791    0.421   0.147
-server2         .GPS.            1 u   66   64  377    9.694    0.255   0.218
#server3          10.10.10.74     2 u   23   64  377    7.376    0.685   0.057
+server4         .PPS.            1 u    3   64  377   16.979   -0.894   0.185
-server5         .DCFa.           1 u   13   64  377    9.016    0.481   0.251
 ntp.mcast.net   .MCST.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.002
 LOCAL(0)        .LOCL.          10 l    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
+SHM(0)          .GPS.            0 l    6   16  377    0.000    6.366   8.976
*SHM(1)          .PPS.            0 l   16   16  377    0.000   -0.046   0.011
associd=0 status=0415 leap_none, sync_uhf_radio, 1 event, clock_sync,
version="ntpd 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Tue May 31 10:09:21 UTC 2016 (1)",
processor="x86_64", system="Linux/4.7.3-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64", leap=00,
stratum=1, precision=-19, rootdelay=0.000, rootdisp=1.225, refid=PPS,
reftime=dbc612ab.93ca4dbf  Thu, Nov  3 2016 19:46:51.577,
clock=dbc612bc.05f5dedc  Thu, Nov  3 2016 19:47:08.023, peer=52638, tc=4,
mintc=3, offset=-0.129, frequency=-68.142, sys_jitter=0.115, clk_jitter=0.051, clk_wander=0.012, tai=36, leapsec=201507010000,
expire=201612010000
```

My leap is un-armed as I've not reloaded to include the latest insertion due at the end of this year.

Comment: thanks and let me check with your script, i'll update you soon with mine output.

Comment: Issue is not reproducable. I'm waiting for an issue. Can you please tell me what logs we need if we get this issue in future to debug?

Comment: I'd keep an eye on `/var/log/messages` and from time to time run `ntpq -pcrv` to check everything is ok. Hopefully you don't get any more problems.

Comment: thanks, actually this NTP service is running on customer machine, so how can I get ntpq -pcrv logs time to time? I don't have control on that machine.

Comment: unless you have access to the machine then its a bit tricky. depending how good your scripting is you can make something that pulls the stats, or you could go down the RRD/MRTG route. nptd is not known for its logging to be honest.